# I want to get attended event of particular lead

Tags: php, sql

I have **`three`** tables.

`1. eventtbl`

`2. user_lead`

`3. event_attendants`

i want to `fetch the records of events based on particular lead,` that which lead has attended how many events. i am so stuck here,anyone can help me with this.

```
eventtbl(Table):
    event_id

event_attendance(Table):    
   event_attendance_id, event_id ,user_id

user_lead(Table):   
    user_id
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Can you explain exactly what type of database you're using (I assume MySQL?), and show us what you've tried? This should increase your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: `SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) FROM event_attendance GROUP BY user_id`

This will give you all the leads with their attendance count

Comment: heya, i got solution, thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right:

```
SELECT
    e.*
FROM
    eventtbl AS e
    JOIN event_attendance AS ea ON (e.event_id = ea.event_id)
    JOIN user_lead AS ul ON (ul.user_id = ea.user_id)
WHERE
    ul.user_id = 123;
```

You could also ommit second join, but I don't know if you want to select more data.

Comment: Actually, both joins are redundant in the simplest case.